# how to transform a dict of lists to a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dict in python like this:

```
d = {"a": [1,2,3], "b": [4,5,6]}
```

I want to transform in a dataframe like this:

| letter | number |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| a | 3 |
| b | 4 |
| b | 5 |
| b | 6 |

i have tried this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(vulnerabilidade, orient = 'index').T
```

but this gave me:

| a | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |
| b | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |

Comment: Your code does not give the output you show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another possible solution:

```
(pd.Series(d, index=d.keys(), name='numbers')
 .rename_axis('letters').reset_index()
 .explode('numbers', ignore_index=True))
```

Output:

```
  letters numbers
0       a       1
1       a       2
2       a       3
3       b       4
4       b       5
5       b       6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always read your data in as you already have and then [`.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) it:

When passed no `id_vars` or `value_vars`, melt turns each of your columns into their own rows.

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {"a": [1,2,3], "b": [4,5,6]}
out = pd.DataFrame(d).melt(var_name='letter', value_name='value')

print(out)
  letter  value
0      a      1
1      a      2
2      a      3
3      b      4
4      b      5
5      b      6
```

Answer (score 1):

To use 'letter' and 'number' as column labels you could use:

```
a2 = [[key, val] for key, x in d.items() for val in x]
dict2 = pd.DataFrame(a2, columns = ['letter', 'number'])
```

which gives

```
  letter  number
0      a       1
1      a       2
2      a       3
3      b       4
4      b       5
5      b       6
```

Answer (score 0):

This will yield what you want (there might be a simpler way though):

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = {"a": [1,2,3], "b": [4,5,6]}

my_list = [[key, val] for key in my_dict for val in my_dict[key] ]
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=['letter','number'])

df
# Out[106]: 
#   letter  number
# 0      a       1
# 1      a       2
# 2      a       3
# 3      b       4
# 4      b       5
# 5      b       6
```